# control + t not working as shown in youtube

Tags: texturing, shaders

I saw many YouTube tutorials of instant PBR texturing; they all say to click ctrl + shift + t, but it doesn't do anything. I saw people saying to click ctrl + t instead. When I did, it didn't open any new window where I can select my texture, but instead it opened empty tabs like the picture I have showed.

[image: this is what it showed]

Comment: Hello, have you enabled the addon called Node Wrangler?

Comment: Almost all of those tutorials say you need to have the Node Wrangler addon enabled, so I repeat the question by @moonboots - do you have it enabled?